# Content isn't aligning downwards correctly when using float tag

Tags: html, css, formatting, css-float

this is my first post so im sorry if i dont give a good explanation to my problem. ive been trying to design a page that has the albumTitle and xhapyArtist classes grouped together on one side, while the date and runtime are grouped on the other side. I tried using float and padding to make this work, and it did for one entry, but if i try to duplicate the entry, it wont line up vertically, and itll basically be displayed left to right as it fits on the page. is there a more efficient way to do this? lmk.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>xhapy's discography</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="author" content="xhapy">
        <meta name="description" content="xhapy's discography, site coded by xhapy">
        <meta name="keywords" content="xhapy, Music, Electronic music, Producer, Artist, xhapy artist, xhapy producer, xhapy albums, xhapy discography, Rap, Hip-Hop, Ambient">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
<!-- 
    HEADER SECTION:
    -   Title
    -   Short comment below title
-->
            
            <hr id="headerbreak1">
            <h1 class="content" id="discTitle">discography</h1>
            <hr id="headerbreak2">
            
            <h2 id="discH2">list of my music dating back to 2017</h2>
            <hr class="content" id="visibleDivider">
            
        </div>
        

        <div id="discography"> 
            
<!--
    DISCOGRAPHY SECTION:
    - The discography section will be sorted from the most
      recent year.
-->
            
    <h1 id=year>2022</h1>
            <div id="album">
                <h2 id="left" class="albumTitle"><a class="albumTitle" href="https://distrokid.com/hyperfollow/xhapy/lostfound-tape" target="_blank">lost&found tape</a></h2>
                <h3 id="left" class="xhapyArtist"><a class="xhapyArtist" href="xhapy.com" target="_blank">xhapy</a></h3>
                <h2 id="right" class="date">September 2022</h2>
                <h3 id="right"  class="runtime">36:28</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="album">
                <h2 id="left" class="albumTitle"><a class="albumTitle" href="https://distrokid.com/hyperfollow/xhapy/lostfound-tape" target="_blank">lost&found tape</a></h2>
                <h3 id="left" class="xhapyArtist"><a class="xhapyArtist" href="xhapy.com" target="_blank">xhapy</a></h3>
                <h2 id="right" class="date">September 2022</h2>
                <h3 id="right"  class="runtime">36:28</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="album">
                <h2 id="left" class="albumTitle"><a class="albumTitle" href="https://distrokid.com/hyperfollow/xhapy/lostfound-tape" target="_blank">lost&found tape</a></h2>
                <h3 id="left" class="xhapyArtist"><a class="xhapyArtist" href="xhapy.com" target="_blank">xhapy</a></h3>
                <h2 id="right" class="date">September 2022</h2>
                <h3 id="right"  class="runtime">36:28</h3>
            </div>
            
        </div>

    
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* STYLE FOR xhapy WEBSITE */

body {
    background-color:black;
    color:white; 
}

th {
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #370404;
    padding: 5px;
}

.content {
    width:900px;
        margin:0  auto
}

.header {
    text-align:center;
    
}

.latest {
    text-align:center;
}

.pages {
    text-align:center;
}

.table {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-spacing: 0 15px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}

#left{
    float: left;
    padding-left:500px;
}

#right{
    float: right;
    padding-right:500px;
}
#title {
    font-size:110px;
}
#discTitle {
    font-size:110px;
    color:#FFC6C6;
}
#headerbreak1 {
    border:black;
    margin: 100px;
}

#headerbreak2 {
    border:black;
    margin: 10px;
}

#discH2{
    color:#FFE2E2;
}

#visibleDivider {
    border-color:darkslategray;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

#xhapyRelease {
    background-color:#071192;
}

#triiwaveRelease {
    background-color:#600000;
}

#xhapyHyperlink {
    color:#B5B8DC;
}

#triiwaveHyperlink {
    color:#FF6F6F;
}

#discHyperlink {
    color:#BB4B4B;
}

#galleryHyperlink {
    color:#BB4B4B;
}

/* DISCOGRAPHY FORMAT */

#year{
    padding-left:500px;
    padding-bottom:25px;
    font-size:50px;
}

#album{
}
.albumTitle {
    color:#EA8DFF;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 0px;
}

.xhapyArtist {
    color:#C154FF;
}

.triiwaveArtist {
    color:#FF5454;
}

.date{
    color:#637671;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 0px;
}

.runtime{
    color:#4D5C58;
}
```

[i want it to look like this](https://i.gyazo.com/e1ab11f7633c47e69cf6409f994a019e.png)
and
[this is what it looks like now](https://i.gyazo.com/6b9fb31e4e368072a08a935d7daa11b4.png)

again sorry if my code is all over the place, i am a very new html/css coder. any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
/* STYLE FOR xhapy WEBSITE */

body {
    background-color:black;
    color:white; 
}    
th {
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #370404;
    padding: 5px;
}    
.content {
    width:900px;
    margin:0  auto
}    
.header {
    text-align:center;        
}    
.latest {
    text-align:center;
}    
.pages {
    text-align:center;
}   
.table {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-spacing: 0 15px;
    border-collapse: separate;
} 
#title {
    font-size:110px;
}
#discTitle {
    font-size:110px;
    color:#FFC6C6;
}
#headerbreak1 {
    border:black;
    margin: 100px;
}    
#headerbreak2 {
    border:black;
    margin: 10px;
}    
#discH2{
    color:#FFE2E2;
}    
#visibleDivider {
    border-color:darkslategray;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}    
#xhapyRelease {
    background-color:#071192;
}    
#triiwaveRelease {
    background-color:#600000;
}    
#xhapyHyperlink {
    color:#B5B8DC;
}    
#triiwaveHyperlink {
    color:#FF6F6F;
}    
#discHyperlink {
    color:#BB4B4B;
}    
#galleryHyperlink {
    color:#BB4B4B;
}

/* DISCOGRAPHY FORMAT */

#year{
    padding-left:15%;
    padding-bottom:25px;
    font-size:50px;
}

#album{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}
.albumTitle {
    color:#EA8DFF;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 0px;
}

.xhapyArtist {
    color:#C154FF;
}

.triiwaveArtist {
    color:#FF5454;
}

.date{
    color:#637671;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 0px;
}

.runtime{
    color:#4D5C58;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>xhapy's discography</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="author" content="xhapy">
    <meta name="description" content="xhapy's discography, site coded by xhapy">
    <meta name="keywords" content="xhapy, Music, Electronic music, Producer, Artist, xhapy artist, xhapy producer, xhapy albums, xhapy discography, Rap, Hip-Hop, Ambient">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <hr id="headerbreak1">
        <h1 class="content" id="discTitle">discography</h1>
        <hr id="headerbreak2">            
        <h2 id="discH2">list of my music dating back to 2017</h2>
        <hr class="content" id="visibleDivider">            
    </div>       
    <div id="discography">             
    <h1 id=year>2022</h1>
        <div id="album">
          <div id="left">
            <h2 id="" class="albumTitle"><a class="albumTitle" href="https://distrokid.com/hyperfollow/xhapy/lostfound-tape" target="_blank">lost&found tape</a></h2>
            <h3 id="" class="xhapyArtist"><a class="xhapyArtist" href="xhapy.com" target="_blank">xhapy</a></h3>
          </div>
          <div id="right">
            <h2 id="" class="date">September 2022</h2>
            <h3 id=""  class="runtime">36:28</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="album">
          <div id="left">
            <h2 id="" class="albumTitle"><a class="albumTitle" href="https://distrokid.com/hyperfollow/xhapy/lostfound-tape" target="_blank">lost&found tape</a></h2>
            <h3 id="" class="xhapyArtist"><a class="xhapyArtist" href="xhapy.com" target="_blank">xhapy</a></h3>
          </div>
          <div id="right">
            <h2 id="" class="date">September 2022</h2>
            <h3 id=""  class="runtime">36:28</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="album">
          <div id="left">
            <h2 id="" class="albumTitle"><a class="albumTitle" href="https://distrokid.com/hyperfollow/xhapy/lostfound-tape" target="_blank">lost&found tape</a></h2>
            <h3 id="" class="xhapyArtist"><a class="xhapyArtist" href="xhapy.com" target="_blank">xhapy</a></h3>
          </div>
          <div id="right">
            <h2 id="" class="date">September 2022</h2>
            <h3 id=""  class="runtime">36:28</h3>
        </div>            
    </div>    
  </div>    
</body>
```